# CNNNetwork getLayerByName alternative for openvino 2021

Tags: openvino

Hi I'm working on Openvino and upgraded recently and found a deprecation I cannot get around.

CNNetwork API getLayerByName was deprecated and removed in Openvino 2021. I am struggling to find an alternative approach with the new API. For now I have just ignored checking if the layer names are what I expect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the CNNNetwork Api getLayerByName was deprecated and the only alternative would be to migrate to IR V10 and modify nGraph function directly. Refer to this documentation https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2020.4/deprecated.html

Comment: Thanks, is there an example of how to do this?